# Instantiation error while running hive query with cassandra handler

Tags: cassandra, hive, hadoop2

Im trying to run a hive query using Cqlstoragehandler the following components

hive 0.11.0
hadoop 2.5.1
cassandra 2.0.6

once I have created table in cassandra, I did the following steps in hive

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE metric (api string, name string, time timestamp, value double) STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.cassandra.cql.CqlStorageHandler' WITH SERDEPROPERTIES("cassandra.cf.name" = "metric","cassandra.host"="192.168.0.244","cassandra.port" = "9160") TBLPROPERTIES ("cassandra.ks.name" = "metrics");
```

I'm able to create the external table.

While I'm running the hive query `select * from metric;`

I'm getting the following error

```
hive> use metrics;
OK
Time taken: 0.018 seconds
hive> show tables;
OK
metric
Time taken: 0.573 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
hive> select * from metric;
OK
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InstantiationError: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cassandra.input.cql.HiveCqlInputFormat.getSplits(HiveCqlInputFormat.java:165)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator.getRecordReader(FetchOperator.java:380)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator.getNextRow(FetchOperator.java:508)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator.pushRow(FetchOperator.java:488)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchTask.fetch(FetchTask.java:136)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.getResults(Driver.java:1412)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:271)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:216)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:413)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:756)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:614)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hive's internal interface -- that the handler relies on -- has changed the last several versions. Unfortunately this means the Cqlstoragehandler requires a specific version of hive. For the version included with Cassandra 2.0.6, only apache hive 12 is compatible (Note: this also excludes Cloudera's version of hive 12).